# Cannot select subcategory field in entity

Tags: categories, field

I have a Structure section `fruit` with a single entry type `fruit`.

I also have a Category `fruitType` with 2 levels:

- Citrus

  - Orange
  - Lemon
  - Lime
- Melons

  - Watermelon
  - Honeydew

The entry type `fruit` has a Category field for `fruitType`.

If I select a level 2 category for the `fruitType` field, say `Orange`:

[image: Category Selection]

Craft CMS dismisses the category selection pop-up and the parent category is shown instead, in this case `Citrus`.

[image: Resulting Category]

From the browser's network inspector, I noticed that a POST request to `/admin/actions/elements/getCategoriesInputHtml` with the following form data:

```
categoryIds[]:893
locale:en_us
id:fields-fruitCategory
name:fields[fruitCategory]
limit:1
selectionLabel:Category
```

However, the response from the server is:

```
{"html":"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fields[fruitCategory]\" value=\"\">\n\n<div id=\"fields-fruitCategory\" class=\"categoriesfield\">\n\t<ul class=\"elements structure\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<li id=\"fields-fruitCategory-category-887\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"row\" style=\"margin-left: -0px; padding-left: 0px;\"><div class=\"element removable\" data-id=\"887\" data-locale=\"en_us\" data-status=\"enabled\" data-label=\"Faculty\" data-url=\"http:\/\/craft.local\/fruit\/citrus\" data-level=\"1\" data-editable><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fields[fruitCategory][]\" value=\"887\"><a class=\"delete icon\" title=\"Remove\"><\/a> <div class=\"label\"><span class=\"status enabled\"><\/span><span class=\"title\">Citrus<\/span><\/div><\/div><\/div>\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/li>\n\t\t\t<\/ul>\n\n\t<div class=\"btn add icon dashed\">Category<\/div>\n<\/div>\n\n"}
```

Based on the response and what's rendered in the interface, Citrus is shown and not Orange, despite Orange being selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike structured entries, when you relate a category to another element, its ancestors are also included in the relation. Due to [the way Craft looks up these ancestors when relating the selected categories, to enforce this behaviour](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/CategoriesService#fillGapsInCategoryIds-detail), the ancestors are added to the relation *before* the one you selected, and it looks like you're limiting that Categories field to **1**, so *only* the parent is being added.

Try setting the limit on that Categories field to **2**.